# find barycenter with only one recursive call

Tags: c, recursion

My professor wrote us the code to find barycenter with only one recursive call. He said that the strategy was to propagate forward the value of sp (right sum), and propagate backwards the value `ss (left sum)`, `*b` should be a parameter to indicate the position of barycenter.

```
int barRecAux( int a[], int i, int n, int sp, int * b ) {
    int ss;

    if ( i == n ) {
        return 0;
    }

    sp += a[i];
    ss = barRecAux( a, i + 1, n, sp, b );

    if ( *b >= 0 ) {
        return ss;
    }

    if ( ss == sp ) {
        *b = i + 1;
        return ss;
    } else {
        return ss + a[i];
    }
}

int barycenRec( int a[], int n, int * k ) {
    *k = -1;
    barRecAux( a, 0, n, 0, k );

    if ( *k < 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The fact is that I don't understand how this code works, for example
what does `*k=-1` mean? Should I consider the first recursive call as
`barRecAux(a, 0, n, 0, -1)`?

```
*k = -1;
barRecAux( a, 0, n, 0, k );

if ( *k < 0 ) {
    return 0;
}
```

And what does this function do?

```
ss = barRecAux( a, i + 1, n, sp, b );

if ( *b >= 0 ) {
    return ss;
}
```

And how can `b` be positive?

Can you give me an example of how the code works? maybe also written in a complete way in order to test it?

Comment: You should indent/format your code properly so it is readable. Even experts have a hard time working with poorly formatted code.

Comment: `*k` (or `*b` in the recursive function) stores the index of the barycenter, which should be non-negative, and −1 is a special value meaning "not found". And "one recursive call" is misleading: The recursive function is called `n` times, which may not be safe for large arrays.

Comment: Add `printf ("In barRecAux() call with N : %d\n", n);` at the top in `barRecAux()`. You'll see how many times it's been called.